# div border collapse not working in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Here's the fiddle without Bootstrap

#### [No Bootstrap](http://jsfiddle.net/amnE6/)

and with bootstrap:

#### [With Bootstrap](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5831/)

What I want is to make a responsive table, but I can't move further because collapse is not working properly.

**Sample HTML:**

```
<div id="feature-box">
<div class="ft-row">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"> 
<span class="feature-deliver"></span>
<h4>
<a href="#" title="Title">Title</a>
</h4>
<p>paragraph</p>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"> 
<span class="feature-deliver"></span>
<h4>
<a href="#" title="Title">Title</a>
</h4>
<p>paragraph</p>
</div>
</div>
```

PS: Just Ignore the php tags.

Comment: NVM I'll just use another approach.

Comment: I only use collapse on the navbar. I go with JQuery UI's slideUp and slideDown effect. You could also use toggle.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this ? http://jsbin.com/kanezeje/1 , just put another row in main columns and give border to that row

Comment: Thanks for the answer but nope this is not what i'm looking for. See http://jsbin.com/kanezeje/2/ . Anyway I already found a different solution.

Comment: @AdrianEnriquez What was your solution?

Comment: @Jason I use divs instead of table and added css media queries.